# Flask:validate_on_submit always false, form.errors empty

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

The validate_on_submit is always false and the form.errors is empty. I'm clueless. Tips? thanks.

app.py:

```
def set_comment(page):
    f = form.CommentForm()
    if f.validate_on_submit():
        db.set_comment(f.text.data, datetime.datetime.utcnow(), page, 1)
    else:
        flash(f.errors)
```

form.py

```
class CommentForm(Form):
    text = TextField('Message')
```

show.html

```
<div id="post_comment">
      <form action="" method="post" name="comment">
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        {{form.text}}
  </div>
```

Comment: for me [this](https://pastebin.com/rHWwJYQC) is working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the action url in the form to the proper URL.

Answer (score 1):

In your template, the submit button is missing:

```
<div id="post_comment">
  <form action="" method="post" name="comment">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
    {{form.text}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <!-- this line -->
  </form>
</div>
```